# Using the GTK file chooser to browse a remote filesystem?

Tags: rust, network-programming, gtk3

My program can use a network protocol to query remote filesystem information (like directory contents). I would like to use the GTK file chooser widget or something similar to allow my users to pick files on the remote server.

However, the GTK file picker handles the interaction with the filesystem itself. I don't see a way to stick my own code in, so although I could write some functions that "pretended" to be a filesystem interface, I don't see a way to get the file chooser to use them. Are there any options for me other than creating my own version of the file picker widget?

Also: I happen to be writing this in Rust. That may or may not be relevant, depending on what your suggestions are. ;)

Comment: I think that GIO has a way to write plugins that can then be used to access any data in a filesystem-like fashion. Once you have such a plugin for your remote filesystem, the GTK file picker should handle it more or less automatically.

Comment: @Jmb It looks like GIO already supports SFTP backends, which will serve my purpose. Thanks so much, you just saved me days of work.